# Code only runs on optimization level 1 (-O1) using ICPX with SYCL application

Tags: optimization, intel, sycl

I am developing a SYCL application using the Intel ICPX compiler. While the code executes successfully in debug mode with the -O0 optimization level, I encounter issues in the release version: the code runs without crashing but yields incorrect results. This problem arises when using higher optimization levels, such as -O2. Standard debugging techniques, like breakpoints, are not very helpful in this scenario as they don't provide useful insights at these optimization levels. Are there any tools or techniques specifically suited for debugging under such high optimization conditions

Comment: In general, this means there is an undefined behaviour in your program (ie. you break the rule of the language). For example, aliasing tends to cause such an issue. It can be more rarely be a bug of the compiler (I found a sneaky one recently on OneAPI tools). The later might be solved by using a newer version of the compiler. Regarding the former, there are sanitizer that can help for that but I do not know if Intel provide such a thing (AFAIK ICPX is based on LLVM which provides sanitizers).

Comment: If ICPX supports options like clang, use `-Wall -O2 -fsanitize=undefined` to warn about stuff at compile time, and to make asm that tries to detect UB at run-time.  Because UB is almost always the cause of things running differently with optimization enabled.  If ICPX doesn't support those options, use a compiler that does like GCC or Clang for testing, even if you have to change your accelerated code to be portable to pure C++.